# How to set PHP syntax for a file without <?php tag?

Tags: php, sublime-text-2

When I set syntax to PHP in Sublime, all thing is good in my PHP code:

[image: code with syntax highlighted]

But when I remove `<?php` tag from my code, the syntax highlighter doesn't work anymore:

[image: code without syntax highlighted]

**How can I tell sublime to do syntax highlighting on this specific file** (my file extension is `.code`)?

Comment: I second the problem. even I have the same issue.

Comment: I was unable to solve this.  I wanted to do it because I was including PHP code using gulp-preprocess, and needed the tags to be excluded.  The only solution I found was to add a step in my gulp build process to strip the tags from the file before processing step.  Kind of silly, but not having the highlighting was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

Put `#<?php` at the top of the file. PHP will treat it as a comment. Sublime won't. Perfect.

Comment: I tried this, but it is far from ideal in my situation.  I was importing a lot of scripts into PHP with a pre-processer, and while, able to prevent the execution of this code, it left a whole bunch of superfluous `#<?php` tags floating throughout the built PHP source file.

Answer (score 0):

With your file open, from the **View** menu, choose **Syntax...**.  Choose one of the options to set the syntax for that file only.  Or, choose **Open All with Current Extension As...** to specify that all .code files should use the PHP syntax.

Comment: I did it before and the Syntax is set to PHP. The problem is because my file doesn't contains `<?php` tag, the Sublime Text won't highlight my code.